# How to find which column meets a criteria first for each row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns [x, y, z] which will have float values.
I want to create a new column that tells me, from every x[row], which column reaches a certain percentage of x[row] first.

So, for example, let's say my x[5] = 2 and my target for y is 10%, while my target for z is -10%, what I want to find out is which one happens first, y >= 2.20 or z =< 1.80, starting from row 5 (doesn't matter if it happens on row 6 or 1.000.000, only if y or z happened first).

This should be a fourth column (and the values could be as simple as 0 for y and 1 for z).
If this value is never met or both columns meet at the same row, it could be a -1.

The result should be a new column that points out which column (y or z) will have a percentual difference first (starting from this row) based on the x for this row.

I could easily do it with a double-loop that iterates through each row (first loop), stores x and start comparing y and z to find which one meets the critera first (second loop). But I know these can usually be solved with pandas functions, making the code cleaner and possibly faster.

here is an example of inputs (3 columns) and outputs (4th column) for my problem (assuming the difference flags were set to 10% (y) and -10% (z):

```
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0][0] // y met the +10% criteria first in row 1 (1.0 -> 1.2)
 [1.2, 1.2, 1.0][1] // z met the -10% criteria first in row 2 (1.2 -> 0.9)
 [1.3, 1.3, 0.9][0] // y met the +10% criteria first in row 3 (1.3 -> 1.6)
 [1.1, 1.6, 1.2][1] // z met the -10% criteria first in row 5 (1.1 -> 0.9)
 [1.8, 1.1, 1.1][1] // z met the -10% criteria first in row 5 (1.8 -> 0.9)
 [1.2, 1.8, 0.9][-1] // none met the criteria
```

Comment: This question as most question would greatly benefit it having some sample input data and expected output.

Comment: Done, didn't create an example for every possible outcome, but that's not necessary as I can work that out, my main problem is how to solve this loop with pandas functions.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use a df['x'].shift(-1) to get your criteria and comparison. But I don't It sounds like a complicated logic, I didn't get it.

I'd suggest you to create your custom logic using numpy arrays, it will probably be faster than using pandas if you use it in a [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) function.

Comment: Numba really made it faster than I expected, solved my problem.
Doing the whole thing with loops would take a few mins to run (that's why I was trying to use Pandas), but with Numba, it takes literally less than a sec.

Thanks!